# Python JSON dump a list of object.

Tags: python, json

I have a list of dictionaries, How do I dump it using JSON one line per dictionary?

I tried:

```
json.dump( d, open('./testing.json','w'), indent=0)
```

where d is the list of dictionaries. But this newlines every (key,value) pair. I want each dictionary in one line. How should I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could turn it into a string with that format before writing it out. This could be done with a combination of a list comprehension and a join:

```
strs = [json.dumps(innerdict) for innerdict in d]
s = "[%s]" % ",\n".join(strs)
open('./testing.json','w').write(s)
```

In one line:

```
open('./testing.json','w').write("[%s]" % ",\n ".join(json.dumps(e) for e in d))
```

or:

```
open('./testing.json','w').write("[%s]" % ",\n ".join(map(json.dumps, d)))
```